# "Closing" files in IsolatedStorage before deleting them

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm writing an app for Windows Phone 7 in which I save images to Isolated Storage.
When I load them, I can't close the opened image streams because other parts of my program need to be able to read them in order to properly display the images.
I only want to close these streams when I'm getting ready to delete/alter the files themselves in Isolated Storage.

However, by the time I'm ready to delete these images, I no longer have access to the local IsolatedStorageFileStream variables I was using when I opened them.

Is there a way to somehow "close" these files at this point (besides restarting my application)? I can't seem to delete them otherwise.

This is how I write the images into IsolatedStorage:

```
    Dictionary<string, Stream> imageDict = (Dictionary<string, Stream>)Globals.CNState["ATTACHMENT"];
    foreach (string pic in imageDict.Keys)
    {
      Stream input = imageDict[pic];
      input.Position = 0;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];

      using (FileStream thisStream = myISF.OpenFile(thisDirectory + pic, FileMode.Create))
      {
        int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (read > 0)
        {
          thisStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
          read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
      }
    }
```

This is how I load them out later (as you can see, I keep them open):

```
  string[] storedImages = myISF.GetFileNames(thisDirectory);
  if(storedImages.Length > 0)
  {
    foreach(string pic in storedImages)
    {
      IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = myISF.OpenFile(thisDirectory + pic, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
      imageDict.Add(pic, imageStream);
    }
  }

  Globals.CNState["ATTACHMENT"] = imageDict;
```

I can't close these because another part of my application needs to create the images from their file streams (this may need to happen multiple times):

```
  if (Globals.CNState != null && Globals.CNState.ContainsKey("ATTACHMENT"))
  {
    imageDict = (Dictionary<string, Stream>)Globals.CNState["ATTACHMENT"];
    foreach (string key in imageDict.Keys)
    {
      Stream imageStream = imageDict[key];

      Image pic = new Image();
      pic.Tag = key;
      BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
      bmp.SetSource(imageStream);
      pic.Source = bmp;
      pic.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 15);
      pic.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pic_MouseLeftButtonUp);
      DisplayPanel.Children.Add(pic);
    }
  }
```

I also need to keep the streams open because another part of my program sends these images to a server, and as far as I know, I can only send a byte stream, not a UIElement.

Comment: Please post your code - how are you writing the files?

Comment: You are going against a basic principle of IsolatedStorage (temporary and fast access) by keeping the streams open. You would never consider doing this if it were a Win Forms app (or you would run out of file handles), so why do it on a device that has severely limited resources? You should either cache the bitmaps or reopen the streams as needed (most apps reload the images on demand, some may cache a few frequently used bitmaps) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with massive data sizes, you should be closing your file streams as soon as you've loaded them into memory. For example, if you're loading an image you should close the stream once you've created the image object.

Comment: I need the streams to stay open because multiple parts of my program depend on them being open to function. Trust me, I don't want it to work this way either, but that's the only way it can work. Please answer my actual question, which is if there is a way to close files without access to the original stream object that was used to open them.

Comment: @WinterRye... it is highly unlikely that the files need to remain open for use as images... as they have to be fully loaded into *in-memory bitmaps* to be visible. After they have loaded the stream can be closed.

Comment: @WinterRye - Direct answer: no. Indirect answer: Have you considered loading the data into a `MemoryStream` and passing _that_ around as your Stream?

Comment: @Richard Szalay - I did try loading the data into a MemoryStream, but I didn't know how to load the data into one without using the "using" block, which closes the MemoryStream at the end